# Is it possible to use START WITH CONNECT BY command in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, recursion

can anyone help me to do a recursive query on my sqlite database?
The command START WITH CONNECT BY might be helpful, but it is not working with me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Oracle's syntax. A bit of Googling reveals that SQLite doesn't support recursive queries; neither using Oracle `connect by` nor ANSI recursive CTEs using the `with` clause. As such, you would have to delegate the recursion logic to your application.

Comment: meanwhile...

this was added in sqlite 3.8.3 
https://www.sqlite.org/changes.html#version_3_8_3

it's documented here:
https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html

Answer (score 4):

As of 2014-02-03, SQLite v3.8.3 it is [totally possible](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html).

Comment: Wow! But we can't do it android since it is v3.4!!